How can I alter the y limits to be max+1 and min-1 in a multifaceted graph?
I don't like the scaling of the graphs in this multifaceted graph. The lines of the graph all sit at the very top. I have freed the scaling, but how can I alter it so that the y limit is always max+1 and min-1? In this case, the min and max relate to the min and max of the data within each facet?
My data:
graphs<-structure(list(Ceramide = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), levels = c("Cer.d18.0.24.0.", 
"Cer.d18.1.17.0.", "Cer.d18.1.24.0.", "GlcCer..d18.1.16.0.", 
"GlcCer..d18.1.22.0.", "GlcCer..d18.1.24.0.", "PC.36.1.", "SM.d18.0.20.0.", 
"SM.d18.1.16.0.", "SM.d18.1.20.0.", "SM.d18.1.22.0.", "SM.d18.1.24.0."
), class = "factor"), Time = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("control", 
"nonsurgery", "surgery"), class = "factor"), Value_mean = c(5.02809699075469, 
5.09503261736845, 5.11452108704046, 5.10278138392437, 5.16750547565784, 
5.07314367565285, 5.03730835244686, 5.06342334762789, 4.96256959017197, 
-Inf, -Inf, -Inf, 2.14759633325181, 2.33052260753621, -Inf, -Inf, 
-Inf, -Inf, 7.56221372288106, 7.61968595395547, 7.64761280308678, 
7.65620351447382, 7.7468877700324, 7.68050496405697, 7.73371317361311, 
7.7381474712009, 7.65902164625821, 4.7547212201086, 4.80997282635855, 
4.83022183766452, 4.91100479506237, 5.01398764937662, 4.93026631877413, 
5.10250549453027, 5.11968531460944, 5.162481536456, 6.37208193214787, 
6.50353553379893, 6.59906327054148, 6.66373047865515, 6.88374652364655, 
6.71916519881229, 6.80614756354964, 6.86512502152463, 6.89764472523546, 
6.15056645070961, 6.24862170313425, 6.33834767497885, 6.43189248212191, 
6.63320845118252, 6.47728959139649, 6.67279983836628, 6.72678337681611, 
6.81883568457303, 10.6710318085797, 10.7438423068138, 10.8435888011329, 
10.8264131474942, 11.0381248165859, 10.894341065071, 10.8605975566617, 
10.9416385585607, 10.9485119392667, 6.99496103560838, 7.11387209825488, 
7.24738042382308, 7.17467462260107, 7.37010595956547, 7.17557347169308, 
7.13136776630543, 7.23741498221748, 7.15649993471, 10.6645576033899, 
10.733938499054, 10.7769597807141, 10.7674789422102, 10.8629406984201, 
10.8169969189115, 10.7665150863578, 10.8095656491845, 10.8558938508093, 
9.88186024568444, 9.9956497125411, 10.1015415439072, 10.0892709843746, 
10.284003303477, 10.0991499404462, 10.1565481211553, 10.2342898563869, 
10.1644482652594, 10.6971170486734, 10.8307846755039, 10.9470292073298, 
10.8926588592777, 11.0813929737297, 10.8992980009711, 10.861669611953, 
10.9522027738501, 10.8639701836629, 9.92791774310726, 10.0605112706741, 
10.1921150939655, 10.1414397716003, 10.3271790949341, 10.1404509499368, 
10.1289660369993, 10.2429340102406, 10.2093817263128), grp = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("control", 
"nonsurgery", "surgery"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-108L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

and the code for my graph:
# Define custom labels for Ceramide names to use in the graph
ceramide_labels <- c("Cer.d18.0.24.0." = "Cer(d18:0/24:0)",
                     "Cer.d18.1.17.0." = "Cer(d18:1/17:0)",
                     "Cer.d18.1.24.0." = "Cer(d18:1/24:0)",
                     "GlcCer..d18.1.16.0." = "GlcCer (d18:1/16:0)",
                     "GlcCer..d18.1.22.0." = "GlcCer (d18:1/22:0)",
                     "GlcCer..d18.1.24.0." = "GlcCer (d18:1/24:0)",
                     "PC.36.1." = "PC(36:1)",
                     "SM.d18.0.20.0." = "SM(d18:0/20:0)",
                     "SM.d18.1.16.0." = "SM(d18:1/16:0)",
                     "SM.d18.1.20.0." = "SM(d18:1/20:0)",
                     "SM.d18.1.22.0." = "SM(d18:1/22:0)",
                     "SM.d18.1.24.0." = "SM(d18:1/24:0)")


 # Creating a multifaceted line plot of the nominally significant ceramides
ggplot(graphs, aes(x = Time, y = Value_mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Ceramide, group = grp), linewidth = 0.5) + # Set line width
  geom_point(aes(shape = grp), size = 2.5) + # Set point color
  facet_wrap(~ Ceramide, scales = "free_y", labeller = labeller(Ceramide = ceramide_labels)) +
  labs(x = "Time Point", 
       y = "Ceramide Value", 
       title = "Nominally Significant Ceramide Means over Time",
       color = "Group") +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(color = "none", shape = guide_legend(title = "Group")) +  # Remove legend
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("0", "2 Years", "6 Years")) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(20, 30, 20, 30, "pt"), 
        panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"),  # Adjust panel spacing
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),  # Remove x-axis ticks
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 8),  # Keep x-axis labels
        strip.text = element_text(size = 8), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +  # Center the plot title
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 1, y = -Inf, yend = 0), color = "black", size = 0.5) + # Add small tick at the bottom to mark the time
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2, xend = 2, y = -Inf, yend = 0), color = "black", size = 0.5) +  
  geom_segment(aes(x = 3, xend = 3, y = -Inf, yend = 0), color = "black", size = 0.5)


Hi Stephr. You can expand the ranges on the y-axes, for example with scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.5)))

I am not want to expand the ranges. I am wanting to wholly decrease them, but add a little bit on top

See ?expansion, the add= argument can be length-2 to affect both ends of the axis.

Right now there is a lot of blank white space and the graphs aren't zoomed in as much as I want for a unit that is very micro in nature. I want to zoom in and center the lines

I will look at that function

This might work. Let me try
